# Is the curve $t \mapsto t \sin \frac 1 t$ rectifiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, arc-length

> Let $a\le 0\le b $ and let $ \gamma : \left[ a,b \right] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
> $\gamma(t)= t\text{sin}\frac{1}{t}$ for $  t\neq 0 $ and $\gamma(t)=0$ for $t=0$. I want to investigate that if this function is rectifiable or not.

I know that for paths or smooth curves being rectifiable is guaranteed. So, since $\gamma'(t) = \sin \frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t} \cos \frac{1}{t}$ for $  t\neq 0 $, $\gamma'$ is continuous and bounded for $  t\neq 0 $, hence a smooth curve and hence rectifiable.

However, I highly doubt that this line of thinking is correct because the function is piecewisely defined, which is my main problem when attacking the problem. I know that there are two equivalent definitions for being rectifiable, one with the sup and the other is a convergence of the net of lengths of polygonal paths. However, I could not find a way to proceed from either definition.

Comment: Just look at the height of each "tent".

Comment: what do you mean by tents

Comment: Sketch the graph of the functi9n and you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The curve $t \mapsto t \sin \frac 1 t$ is not rectifiable.**

First, a curve $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said *rectifiable* when the sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n |\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})|$ where $a \leq t_0 < \dotsc < t_n \leq b$ are bounded above by a finite constant (independent of $n$).

Heuristically, a good indicator of whether a curve is rectifiable is that $\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)| \mathrm{d}t$ is finite. Here, this is not the case. As you computed, $\gamma'(t)$ contains a factor of the form $\frac 1 t \cos t$, which is not integrable near $0$ (*unlike you mention, it is not bounded for $t \neq 0$; and the problem is thus not so much about the piecewise nature of the definition, but more about the competition between oscillation speed and amplitude*).

Hence, we now want to disprove that the finite sums are uniformly bounded above. As sketched in @salcio's comment, after plotting the graph, we get the idea to use points $t_i$ such that $\sin \frac{1}{t_i} = +1$ and $\sin \frac{1}{t_{i-1}} = -1$, so located at opposite sides of the oscillations,  to maximize the arc length.

More precisely, for any $p \geq 1$, we define
$$
\begin{align}
t_{2p} & = - \left(2 p \pi - \frac \pi 2\right)^{-1}, \\
t_{2p+1} & = - \left(2 p \pi + \frac \pi 2\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$
This defines an increasing sequence of points, which satisfies $a < t_i < 0$ for $i \geq p_0$ large enough. Hence, we can consider a partition of the form $a < t_{2p_0} < t_{2p_0+1} < \dotsb < t_{2p_1} < t_{2p_1+1} < b$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=2p_0+1}^{2p_1+1} |\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})|
\geq \sum_{p = p_0}^{p_1} |\gamma(t_{2p+1})-\gamma(t_{2p})|
= \sum_{p = p_0}^{p_1} |t_{2p+1}+t_{2p}|
\geq \sum_{p=p_0}^{p_1} \frac{2}{p \pi}.
$$
Since the sum $\sum_{p = p_0}^{\infty} \frac 1 p$ diverges, we can make these arc lengths arbitrarily large by choosing $p_1$ large enough. This disproves the existence of an arc length of $\gamma$.

Comment: So, the fact that function is defined to be zero for $t=0$ is simply because of the term $1/t$, i.e., the curve $t \mapsto  t\text{sin}\frac{1}{t}$ is not rectifiable where $t \in  [a,b]$ for any value of $a$ and $b$, even if $a$ and $b$ are both positive or both negative? Also, for the case that $a$ and $b$ are both positive, we can define the same sequence for $t_i$ but with minus signs in your definition dropped, making it a decreasing sequence so that $0<a<t_i<b$ for $i\ge p_0$ large enough?

Comment: $\gamma(0) = 0$ ensures that $\gamma$ is *continuous* on, say, $[-1,1]$. Caution: the curve $\gamma$ **is rectifiable** on $[a,b]$ when $0 < a < b$ (or both negative). Indeed, in this case, $\gamma \in C^1([a,b])$ with $\gamma'$ uniformly bounded above on $[a,b]$ (roughly by $1/a$). The issue is that this bound diverges as $a \to 0$. In some sense, you could say that the curve $\gamma$ is **not rectifiable** on $(0,1]$ (you don't need to actually cross $0$, or care about the value at $0$, but you need to get very close to violate the definition of rectifiability).

Comment: I see, so due to the natue of the question, we can make the curve rectifiable only if we take $a=b=0$?

Comment: Yes. The singleton $\{ 0 \}$ is some kind of degenerate rectifiable curve.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $\vec{r}(t)=\langle t, t\sin\left( \frac{1}t\right)\rangle$ be the curve $C$. Given a partition $\{t_0, t_1,\dots, t_n \}$ of interval $[a, b]$, the length of a polynonal path through the curve is

$$L_P(C)=\sum_{k=1}^n \left|\vec{r}(t_k)-\vec{r}(t_{k-1}) \right| $$

From the plot, we can see

$$L_P(C)=\sum \text{length of black lines}$$

We want to show this sum diverges when $n\to\infty$. The total length of $L_p(C)$ contains two parts, black lines above x-axis and black lines below x-axis. Hence,

$$L_P(C)>\sum \text{length of black lines above x-axis}$$

For each "tent" above x-axis, for example, in $\triangle ABC$, $AB+AC>h_1$, hence

$$L_P(C)>\sum_k h_k$$

where $h_k$ is the height of the "peak" of each "tent" above x-axis. Note each "peak" occurs when $f'(t)=0\cap f(t)>0$, where $f(t)=t\sin\left( \frac{1}t\right)$.
$$f'(t)=0\Rightarrow \tan\left( \frac{1}t\right)=\frac{1}t$$
We can't solve the roots analytically from above equation, hence, instead we consider those green-colored height $\color{green}{b_k}$, where occurs at

$$\sin\left( \frac{1}t\right)=1\Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi}$$

so we get

$$\color{green}{b_k}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi}\sin\left( \frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi}>\frac{1}{2(k+1)\pi}$$

and

$$L_P(C)>\sum_k h_k>\sum_k b_k>\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_k\frac{1}{(k+1)}$$

Since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)}$ is divergent, the length of curve $C$ is divergent, hence, it is not rectifiable.